# Excel Multiple conditions to fill a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to learn the Excel formatting and need some help. I have an excel sheet where I keep the profiles of people(name, last name, performance, ....). I do have multiple copies of the same person(let's call him Bill Gates) on my sheet as I am copying it from another source (every week). So last week I marked Bill's "Performance" column as a "Top Performer". When I copy (from a different source) again this week, if there is Bill Gates among the copied ones, I want Excel to auto-fill the "Performance" column of a new copy as a "Top Performer", because I already have marked him before. I hope I could explain my issue. Thanks a lot for your help and support.
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb1QL.png)

Comment: `VLOOKUP()`, `Index/Match`? what have you tried?

Comment: @BruceWayne I haven't tried any of them yet. I looked at IF conditions, but could not make multiple conditions.

Comment: Is Bill Gates in a column, a row, multiple columns, or rows? Sample snapshots of input and output will make your question clearer.

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded a screenshot. So, I copied rows 7-10 from a different spreadsheet. If a copied person (for ex: Bill Gates match) was already in my spreadsheet before and if the "Performance" column of that person was already marked as "Top Performer" before, I want Excel to automatically mark the "Performance" column of the copied one as "Top Performer" too. Note: I want to keep both copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will mark each additional name that qualified previously as a "Top Performer", starting in cell C7 :
   =IF(AND(MATCH(A7,$A$1:A6,0)=MATCH(B7,$B$1:B6,0),INDEX($C$1:C6,MATCH(A7,$A$1:A6,0),1)="Top Performer"),"Top Performer","")

Comment: Thanks @Roger H. It worked :). Can I ask one more thing? What if the FirstName and LastName are concatenated into one column? I mean "Bill Gates" is in one cell under the "Name" column (not divided into two columns FirstName and LastName). Do I just delete the second condition for matching?

Comment: @ Ben K: With the entire name now in Column A, I will assume the "Performance" Column is now Column B.This formula will account for the concatenation: =IFERROR(IF(INDEX(B$1:B6,MATCH(A7,A$1:A6,0),1)="Top Performer","Top Performer",""),"")